# relative url html

Tags: html, css

How do i reference a file template.css from index.php . This file is located within the folder "css" where index.php and  css are at the same level.

index.php
css -> template.css

```
css/template.css
```

does not work

Comment: That should work, or try explicitly `./css/template.css`.

Comment: Can you post the entire link tag? Maybe something else is wrong. `css/template.css` is correct given what you said.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Have you tried anything?***

Try following things:

1. `./css/template.css`
2. `/css/template.css`
3. `css/template.css`

Answer (score 1):

This should work `./css/template.css`. `./` refers to the current working directory.
This also works: `/css/template.css`, but there might be a problem in some unix systems as `/` usually refers to the root folder (of the project).

Answer (score 0):

Are you linking the .css file correctly?

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/template.css"/>
```

in the `<head>` tag.

If so it could be that the permissions are incorrect on the .css file.
Check that the .css file can be read by the user that the web server runs as.

Comment: Why is there a / before the closing tag?